# (Solved) error:\n Variable not in scope: main :: GHC.Types.IO a0 in English Auction

Tags: plutus, plutus-pioneer-program, plutus-playground

I'm trying to compile the English Auction script on a local plutus-playground-client session and I'm getting this error:

```
 error:\n    Variable not in scope: main :: GHC.Types.IO a0
```

Any help on why this is?

Answer (score 4):

You have to delete the module declaration at the top of the file. Try that and recompile. Lars mentions this here: https://youtu.be/K61Si6iQ-Js?t=86

P.S. I missed this originally as well!

Comment: Welcome to Cardano SE! As a new user be sure to take the [Tour].

Answer (score 1):

Yes removing the module declaration works. Sorry to miss that!